# regex expression for latitude and longitude with range -90 to 90 and -180 to 180 in angular 2

Tags: regex, angular

I was trying to put range validation for latitude and longitude by below pattern validation.

For Longitude the range is from -180 to 180 when I am trying to give something like 100 or -100 its giving me an error message

```
^-?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,4})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[1-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?))$
```

Comment: simple answer: 1[1-7][0-9] doesn't match 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you 
Latitue = -90 to +90 and Longitude -180 to + 180

```
^([-+]?\d{1,2}[.]\d+),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}[.]\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex for latitude and longitude

Latitude -90 to +90

```
^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)$
```

Longitude -180 to +180

```
^[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```